# Running JQuery code in Admin Overlay

Tags: modal-dialogs, users

I have an overlay module installed which allows my admin to open in an Overlay (Jquery Pop Up)

I want to run a specific JQuery code whenever admin page opens in an overlay. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `hook_overlay_child_initialize()`

```
<?php

function YOURMODULE_overlay_child_initialize() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURMODULE') . '/YOURMODULE-overlay.js');
}

?>
```

and in file `YOURMODULE-overlay.js` add:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.YOURMODULE = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // Your jQuery code here
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```